# Using EE as a data source for an iphone app

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, authentication

We're currently developing an html5 based iOS app using ExpressionEngine as the data source. So far it's working and looking great. However, we're unsure as to how approach the member side of things: we want to allow users to log in as they do on the main website. This appears to be somewhat of a challenge and we're wondering if anyone has come across a solution?

We're also using Zoo Visitor, but I don't think that's so relevant? It's the member authentication side of things we don't know how to tackle.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Jim

Comment: jim, shoot me an email, i have something in the works that could help you out but am keeping it under wraps in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after going to EEUK13 and seeing Ben Croker's talk, we're going to be using his lovely Open API module to deal with this stuff. If anyone wants to check it out, here's the link: 
https://github.com/putyourlightson/open-api

Answer (score 1):

EE has it's in-built function to authenticate users.

```
$this->EE = & get_instance();

$this->EE->load->library('auth');
$this->EE->load->loadfile('member');

$session_user = $this->EE->auth->authenticate_username($username,$password);
// start the usersession
$session_user->start_session();
```

For subsequent calls, ensure that the session exists.